# MVC page refresh issue after file download

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

**Requirement:**

We have UI that offers user to download a file from server. On this page we also have a string that denotes download recent download time that comes from the server.

The file(.csv) can contain single to multiple thousands records so download time is not predefined.

**Issue:**

We basically need both the file as well as the download time. I cannot do multiple returns from controller action i.e. FileResult and RedirectToAction() at a same time.

**Solutions tried:**
1.  jQuery promises (`When()`), but jQuery functions are getting executed before server call starts. 
2.  Refresh page after 5 sec or any predefined time on download roster button click. But if file download takes more time then page gets refreshed earlier and download roster call gets killed automatically.
3. I tried Ajax, but Ajax does not support return type as FileResult in MVC.
Below is my code from controller, view and script for your reference.

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult DownloadCompleteRoster()
 {
     var rosterResponse = _rosterService.SaveCompleteRoster(User.EmployerId, User.UserId);
     if (rosterResponse.IsSuccess)
     {
         return File(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(rosterResponse.RosterFile.ToString()), "text/csv", rosterResponse.FileName);
     }
     TempData["ErrorMessage"] = rosterResponse.ErrorMessage;
     return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");
 }
```

View:

```html
<div>
    <a href="#" id="downloadCompleteRoster" class="btn secondary mt10">Download Roster File</a>
    @if (Model.LastCompleteDownloadDate != null)
    {
        <span class="small lastDownloaded"><em><strong>Last Downloaded:</strong> @string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", Model.LastCompleteDownloadDate)</em></span>
    }
</div>

<script>    
    var urlDownloadCompleteRoster = '@Url.Action("DownloadCompleteRoster", "Admin")';
</script>
```

JQuery Script:

```
$("#downloadCompleteRoster").click(function () {
    DownloadCompleteRoster();
});

//download complete roster csv file 
function DownloadCompleteRoster() {
    window.location.href = urlDownloadCompleteRoster;
}
```

Comment: When you return File from your action, it sends header which tells the browser to open a file. You can not handle some callback when the download is done or not. Clicking button which opens download link in the same browser window will stop your javascript code. what you can is to implement controller action which will send you bytes, receiving these bytes on the client using javascript, and create the file on the client side using HMTL5 file api. This way you can, show progress,calculate download time etc.